Обращение к данным вложенного массива C++ и оптимизация

Представим вложенный(двумерный) массив 10x10, хранящий числовые
значения.  Классический способ перебора значений, который я обычно
встречаю - это вложенный цикл,  последовательно читающий элементы 1-й
"строки", а затем переходящий к следующей.
Если каждая из таких строк, занимает отдельную область памяти,
то будет 10 переходов по этим областям, и по 10 обращений к
отдельным элементам в строках.
(Шаблон:  element = array[X][Y])
Насколько мне известно, обращение к строке(X) - будет стоить дороже по
вычислительным ресурсам, чем к элементу в ней(Y).

ВОПРОС:
При обращениях к элементам массива не последовательно, и с более частыми перескакиваниями между строк(что в сумме даст больше 10-ти переходов), время перебора увеличится ?

Только не бейте, если вопрос на деле глупый. У меня всё ещё серьёзные дыры в познаниях касаемо работы с памятью.

Встречный вопрос: зачем вам два аккаунта?...

Это не имеет отношения к теме, но у меня 1 аккаунт. Просто сходила в паспортный стол имя пропатчить.

Наверное нужны указатели, если обращаться к строкам массива через указатели, то это богоугодное дело.

В классических массивах все строки расположены в памяти подряд, без разрывов между ними. Поэтому переход от последнего элемента строки к первому в следующей будет выполняться за то же время. Вообще, обмен между памятью (DDR) и кэшем (именно оттуда процессор выбирает данные) происходит кусками по 64 байта  (они называются строками кэша). Именно такая гранулярность может оказать влияние на скорость доступа к данным (но, при последовательном доступе современные процессоры заранее подкачивают несколько следующих строк кэша, так что разница во времени доступа будет не видна)

Благодарю за помощь avp. Приятно встретить того кто share-it.

У вас не указано, какой, собственно двумерный массив имеется в виду. Так что возьмем простейший: int arr[10][10];
Чтоб посильнее "прыгать", просуммируем построчно и постолбцово...
int enumer1()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            sum += arr[i][j];
    return sum;
}
int enumer2()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            sum += arr[i][j];
    return sum;
}

Скомпилируем и поищем различия в ассемблерном коде.
?enumer2@@YAHXZ PROC                                  ?enumer1@@YAHXZ PROC                                 ; enumer2, COMDAT

; 31   :     int sum = 0;                             ; 23   :     int sum = 0;

        xor     eax, eax                                      xor     eax, eax
        lea     r8, OFFSET FLAT:?arr@@3PAY0CHBA@HA            lea     r8, OFFSET FLAT:?arr@@3PAY0CHBA@HA   ; arr
        mov     edx, eax                                      mov     edx, eax
        npad    5                                             npad    5
$LL4@enumer2:                                         $LL4@enumer1:

; 32   :     for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)              ; 24   :     for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
; 33   :         for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)          ; 25   :         for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
; 34   :             sum += arr[i][j];                ; 26   :             sum += arr[i][j];

        mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+32]                    mov     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+32]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+28]                    add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+28]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+24]                    add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+24]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+20]                    add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+20]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+16]                    add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+16]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+12]                    add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+12]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+8]                     add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+8]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+4]                     add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+4]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+36]                    add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8+36]
        add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8]                       add     ecx, DWORD PTR [rdx+r8]
        add     rdx, 40000                                    add     rdx, 40000                           ; 00009c40H
        add     eax, ecx                                      add     eax, ecx
        cmp     rdx, 400000                                   cmp     rdx, 400000                          ; 00061a80H
        jl      SHORT $LL4@enumer2                            jl      SHORT $LL4@enumer1

; 35   :     return sum;                              ; 27   :     return sum;
; 36   : }                                            ; 28   : }

        ret     0                                             ret     0
?enumer2@@YAHXZ ENDP                                  ?enumer1@@YAHXZ ENDP                                 ; enumer2

Вы тоже разницы не видите? :)
Ладно, отключим оптимизацию. Циклы выглядят одинаково, сами обращения к элементам массива тоже:
; 26   :             sum += arr[i][j];          ; 34   :             sum += arr[i][j];

movsxd  rax, DWORD PTR i$1[rsp]                 movsxd  rax, DWORD PTR i$1[rsp]
imul    rax, rax, 40000                         imul    rax, rax, 40000
lea     rcx, OFFSET FLAT:?arr@@3PAY0CHBA@HA     lea     rcx, OFFSET FLAT:?arr@@3PAY0CHBA@HA
add     rcx, rax                                add     rcx, rax
mov     rax, rcx                                mov     rax, rcx
movsxd  rcx, DWORD PTR j$2[rsp]                 movsxd  rcx, DWORD PTR j$2[rsp]
mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+rcx*4]              mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax+rcx*4]
mov     ecx, DWORD PTR sum$[rsp]                mov     ecx, DWORD PTR sum$[rsp]

Так что для массива int[][], память для которого выделяется одним куском, разницы по сути никакой. Особенно та таких размерах, когда весь массив спокойно размещается в кэше процессора...
Но вот если рассмотреть
int ** arr = new int*[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) arr[i] = new int[10];

разница, наконец, появится. Но поймать ее на матрице 10х10 вряд ли вы сумеете. Вот на 1000х1000 - уже реальнее. Смотрите код с результатами здесь: https://bit.ly/3Y091w6
Ваша любознательность удовлетворена?
